# Is there a "Identity (Analysis)" tool for QGIS?

Tags: qgis

In ArcGIS, there is a tool called "[Identity](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000n000000)." Say you have a bunch of points. Some points fall in polygons of interest, some don't. Each polygon has a unique ID. This tool will add a field to the points and assign the unique ID of the polygon that contains it. Is there a tool that does this in QGIS?

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75480/identity-overlay-in-qgis) question does not ask the same question I am.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to assign the ID's of the points that fall into polygons, try using the Join Attributes by Location tool:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The plugin 'Point sampling tool' is an excellent plugin, that will let you pick any field from any vector polygon layer. The plugin also works on raster tables.

[image]