# Is there any plugin to Identity in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

Identity is one of ESRI ArcGIS Feature that clipping feature class by another feature class then union first feature class to the result of clip process.

The simple explanation is like this picture below.
[image: ESRI ArcGIS Identity]

Is there any plugin or feature like this in QGIS?
I'm using QGIS 2.14 Essen.

Comment: I think a similar question was asked before which might help: [Is there a “Identity (Analysis)” tool for QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137352/is-there-a-identity-analysis-tool-for-qgis)

Comment: Yes it is. But no answer yet, and I attached the picture for explaination

Comment: This question, and its answer are different from the linked question. That answer does not cut or clip inputs, like the tool in ArcGIS. The answer given on this question does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Saga install in the processing toolbox has an Identity tool that I think replicates the ArcGIS process.  There appears to be no QGIS help file but the SAGA helpfile is here: http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_module_doc/2.1.3/shapes_polygons_19.html

[image]

Comment: The name seems to have been updated to 'Polygon Identity' in Qgis 3.16